# Python: generate filename by column value

Tags: python, excel

I have table with several thousand lines.
I need to create a function what makes urls like in pictures column. 
It takes npictures number, url and create new urls separate "|".

```
| npictures |         url          |                                pictures                                |
|-----------|----------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|         2 | test.com/img/abc.jpg | test.com/img/abc.jpg | test.com/img/abc_2.jpg                          |
|         3 | test.com/img/def.jpg | test.com/img/def.jpg | test.com/img/def_2.jpg | test.com/img/def_3.jpg |
|         1 | test.com/img/ghi.jpg | test.com/img/ghi.jpg
```

If it possible to make in Excel or make a function in python.

Comment: Best practice: Read docs. Try something. If that doesn't work, read docs. If you still don't get it, describe your goal and your attempts

Comment: What do you mean underscores? If you mean actual hyperlinks, Excel doesn't allow having more than one per cell.

Comment: Your 'url' column lists images. That doesn't make sense. Are you sure it shouldn't be showing a web page url? Or at least a directory/folder?

Comment: @cwallenpoole Thanks for your advice. I trying to make something, but don't get what I need.

Comment: @zwer I mean symbol  '_'. Add in filename at url '_' with number of npictures, but if npictures = 1, return just url.

Comment: @Gary02127 I'm sure that in url column shows url of the file.

Comment: Okay. What's the relationship between 'url' and 'pictures'?

Comment: @Gary02127 I have table with column 'npictures' where the number of images by the column 'url'. Name of the files different the number from 'npictures' column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform one (filename, number) pair using this example program:

```
def f(filename, n):
  res = filename
  for i in range(2, n+1):
    res += ' | ' + filename[:-4] + '_' + str(i) + '.jpg'
  return res

print(f('test.com/img/abc.jpg', 3))
# test.com/img/abc.jpg | test.com/img/abc_2.jpg | test.com/img/abc_3.jpg
```

If your data is a csv, the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) should help you to both read and write csv files in Python.